# RTNETLINK answers: File exists Failed to bring up eth0

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I have 3 identical servers which I SSH into, but couldn't on one of them after a restart.

service networking restart just bring up "RTNETLINK answers: File exists Failed to bring up eth0"

route just shows

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.16.0.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
176.123.62.0    *               255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

But on a working server

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.16.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.16.0.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
176.123.62.0    *               255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

The /etc/network/interfaces file is identical (obviously with different ip addresses, which are fake here)

```
The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 176.123.62.999
        netmask 255.255.254.0
        gateway 172.16.0.1

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
        address 172.16.0.999
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: address cannot contain 999 Check this

Comment: I know, I'm not going to put my real ip addresses on here, there dummy ones

Comment: So no one knows then????

Comment: Helloooo????????